# Conditional Dynamic validator using "Python Descriptors"

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-descriptors

I want to build a simple "DataSource" class with has attributes named as "data_source_type" and "data_source_path". Where "data_source_type" is a ENUM and "data_source_path" is a string, depending on "data_source_type" I want to set appropriate validations like "ValidFilePath" or "ValidHttpURL" to "data_source_path".

I don't want to write IF-ELSE and have a spaghetti data-source class, I want to leverage  "Python Descriptors" or Any other elegant Python constructs which would consider SRP ( Single Responsibility Principle ) and support functional programming construct.

**data_source.py**

```
1 import re
2 from enum import Enum
3 import os
4
5
6 class ValidFilePath(object):
7     def __set__(self, obj, val):
8         if not os.path.exists():
9             raise ValueError("Please enter a valid file path")
10             self.__url = val
11
12     def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
13         return self.__url
14
15
16 class ValidHttpURL(object):
17     def __set__(self, obj, val):
18         if (val is None or re.compile(
19                 r'^https?://'  # http:// or https://
20                 r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|'  # domain...
21                 r'localhost|'  # localhost...
22                 r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'  # ...or ip
23                 r'(?::\d+)?'  # optional port
24                 r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE).search(val) is None):
25             raise ValueError("Please set an valid HTTP(S) URL")
26             self.__url = val
27
28     def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
29         return self.__url
30
31
32 class DataSourceType(Enum):
33     HTTP = 100,
34     LOCAL_FILE = 200,
35     HDFS_FILE = 300
36
37
38 class ValidDataSourceType(object):
39     def __set__(self, obj, val):
40         if val is None or not DataSourceType.__contains__(DataSourceType[val]):
41             raise ValueError("Please set a valid Data Source Type Enum, "
42                              " possible values are -> ", [e.name for e in DataSourceType])
43         self.__data_source_type = DataSourceType[val]
44
45     def __get__(self, obj, objtype):
46         return self.__data_source_type
47
48
49 class DataSource(object):
50     data_source_type = ValidDataSourceType()
51     data_source_path = ValidHttpURL()
```

In line number 51 as of now I have put "ValidHttpURL", where I want to set the appropriate validation descriptor depending on the "data_source_type"

Expected behavior

```
ds1 = DataSource()
ds1.data_source_type = 'HTTP'
ds1.data_source_path = 'http://www.google.com'
ds2 = DataSource()
ds2.data_source_type = 'LOCAL_FILE'
ds2.data_source_path = '/var/www/index.html'
print("All is well")
```

Actual behavior

```
ds1 = DataSource()
ds1.data_source_type = 'HTTP'
ds1.data_source_path = 'http://www.google.com'
ds2 = DataSource()
ds2.data_source_type = 'LOCAL_FILE'
ds2.data_source_path = '/var/www/index.html'

**ValueError: Please set an valid HTTP(S) URL**
```

***UPDATED ANSWER ****

```
  1 import os
  2 import re
  3 from enum import Enum
  4 from weakref import WeakKeyDictionary
  5
  6
  7 def valid_file_path(value):
  8     if not os.path.exists(value):
  9         raise ValueError(value, " is not present. Please make sure the file exists")
 10     return value
 11
 12
 13 def valid_http_url(value):
 14     if (value is None or re.compile(
 15             r'^https?://'  # http:// or https://
 16             r'(?:(?:[A-Z0-9](?:[A-Z0-9-]{0,61}[A-Z0-9])?\.)+[A-Z]{2,6}\.?|'  # domain...
 17             r'localhost|'  # localhost...
 18             r'\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})'  # ...or ip
 19             r'(?::\d+)?'  # optional port
 20             r'(?:/?|[/?]\S+)$', re.IGNORECASE).search(value) is None):
 21         raise ValueError("Please set an valid HTTP(S) URL")
 22     return value
 23
 24
 25 class DataSourceType(Enum):
 26     NOT_DEFINED = (0, None)
 27     HTTP = (100, valid_http_url)
 28     LOCAL_FILE = (200, valid_file_path)
 29
 30     def __init__(self, enum_id, enum_validator):
 31         self._id = enum_id
 32         self._validator = enum_validator
 33
 34     @property
 35     def validator(self):
 36         return self._validator
 37
 38
 39 class ValidDataSourceType(object):
 40     def __init__(self):
 41         self.default = DataSourceType.NOT_DEFINED
 42         self.values = WeakKeyDictionary()
 43
 44     def __get__(self, instance, owner):
 45         return self.values.get(instance, self.default)
 46
 47     def __set__(self, instance, value):
 48         if value is None or not DataSourceType.__contains__(DataSourceType[value]):
 49             raise ValueError("Please set a valid Data Source Type Enum, "
 50                              " possible values are -> ", [e.name for e in DataSourceType])
 51         self.values[instance] = DataSourceType[value]
 52
 53     def __delete__(self, instance):
 54         del self.values[instance]
 55
 56
 57 class ValidDataSourcePath(object):
 58     def __init__(self, default_data_source_type_field='data_source_type'):
 59         self._default = ''
 60         self._default_data_source_type_field = default_data_source_type_field
 61         self.values = WeakKeyDictionary()
 62
 63     def __get__(self, instance, owner):
 64         return self.values.get(instance, self._default)
 65
 66     def __set__(self, instance, *value):
 67         data_source_type_field = self._default_data_source_type_field
 68         value_to_set = None
 69
 70         if value and len(value) == 1 and isinstance(value[0], str):  # user sent only the value
 71             value_to_set = value[0]
 72         if value and len(value) == 1 and isinstance(value[0], tuple):  # user sent the value , and the validation field
 73             value_to_set = value[0][0]
 74             data_source_type_field = value[0][1]
 75
 76         _data_source_type = getattr(instance, data_source_type_field, None)
 77         if not _data_source_type:
 78             raise ValueError(" Valid source path depends on ValidDataSourceType , "
 79                              " please make sure you have an attribute named ValidDataSourceType")
 80         _data_source_type.validator(value_to_set)
 81         self.values[instance] = value_to_set
 82
 83
 84 class DataSource(object):
 85     data_source_type = ValidDataSourceType()
 86     data_source_path = ValidDataSourcePath()
 87
 88
 89 class SomeOtherDomainModel(object):
 90     data_source_type_ext = ValidDataSourceType()
 91     data_source_path = ValidDataSourcePath()
 92
 93
 94 print(" **************** Scenario 1 - Start **************** ")
 95 ds1 = DataSource()
 96 ds1.data_source_type = 'HTTP'
 97 ds1.data_source_path = "http://www.google.com"
 98 print(ds1.data_source_path)
 99 print(" **************** Scenario 1 - End **************** ")
100
101 print(" **************** Scenario 2 - Start **************** ")
102 ds2 = SomeOtherDomainModel()
103 ds2.data_source_type_ext = 'HTTP'
104 ds2.data_source_path = ("http://www.yahoo.com", 'data_source_type_ext')
105 print(ds2.data_source_path)
106 print(" **************** Scenario 2 - Start **************** ")
```

Comment: Basics of my answer (I'll post a full reply when I get the chance): 1) The source type object should contain the name and the validator in one. Enums do allow for this in Python (https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html#planet). 2) make source path into a simple property that runs through the validator stored in the source type.

Comment: @jacob-zimmerman Update as per suggestion but facing issue at line 62 and 63. Not able to associate a descriptor from ENUM at line 71 because it is not created yet

Comment: No, I would write an actual `@property` instead that uses the `data_source_type`. If you'd really like to use a custom descriptor, have `ValidDataSourcePath` assume `obj` has a `data_source_type` and use that instead of storing it on itself. It's hacky, but I can't think of anything else.

Answer (score 1):

So, building off my comments above, here's how DataSource would look (using `@property`), along with the idea that the validator classes should just be functions that return a boolean of whether the path is valid (and raises an error if it would like) instead of being more descriptors:

```
class DataSource(object):
    data_source_type = ValidDataSourceType()

    @property
    def data_source_path(self):
        # can put in a check to make sure _data_source_path exists
        return _data_source_path

    @data_source_path.setter
    def data_source_path(self, path):
        if self.data_source_type.validator(path):
            self._data_source_path = path
```

Descriptors can be difficult to work with and around (I should know; I literally [wrote the book](http://amzn.to/2B4Vj2Z)), and should be avoided when a simpler solution can be found, so that's why I turned your validators into predicate functions. There is also no shame in using `@property` instead of a custom descriptor.

Comment: I did not want to build a direct dependency on properties. The scenario was more of , the validation can be provided by an instance member at runtime by a property named as validator. I got it working , update the answer in the question , please provide if you have any recommendation or suggestion

Comment: Well, as you can see, there has to be *some* sort of connection between the two because they work together. Your solution is probably about the best you can do.